# auto backup derby database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, derby, activerecord-jdbc

I am using **gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'**. In my **database.yml** i am giving

```
adapter: jdbcderby
```

I want to take the auto backup of database after each hour. I did not find any way to take the derby database dump.

Kindly help me in taking derby database dump in rails. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for this

dblook -d 'jdbc:derby://127.0.0.1:3000/db/development;' -t users -o dump.sql

Comment: i already tried this but it gives the error

java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Insufficient data while reading from the network - expected a minimum of 6 bytes and received only -1 bytes.  The connection has been terminated.

Comment: Perhaps that's not the correct IP address and port number for your Derby database?